# register a class in objective c

Tags: objective-c, observer-pattern, decoupling

lets say i have `classA` which is a class  of audio,that sample the audio input many times.
each time `class A` get a new data (can happen many times in second), he needs to inform another class, which is `classB`.

Now, i could just make an instance of `class B`  in `classA` and call B when there is a new data arrived, but this is not a modular software.

i want `classA` to be "blind" to the outside, and just to add him to every project, and to have another `classB` that will `register` him some how, so when A has something new, B will know about it,(without A calling B ! )

how its done right in objective c ?

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *post* a notification in `ClassA`, and *register* for that notification in other classes (namely `ClassB`).

This is how you can do it:

(in `ClassA`):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"noteName" object:self];
```

(in `ClassB`):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(doSomething:)
name:@"noteName" object:nil];
```

Whenever an instance of `ClassA` posts a new notification, other instances that have *registered* to that notification will be informed (instantaneously). In this case, `ClassB` will perform `doSomething:(NSNotification *)note`.

---

[Edit]

You can post that notification your setter method (`setVar:(NSString*)newVar`).

If you want to pass something along, use the `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` variant. `userInfo` is a `NSDictionary` and you can pass anything you want in it. for example:

```
NSDictionary* dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:var, @"variable", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
postNotificationName:@"noteName" object:self userInfo:dic];
```

now, edit your `doSomething:` method:

```
-(void)doSomething:(NSNotification*)note {
    if ([[note name] isEqualToString:@"noteName"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [note userInfo]);
    }
}
```

---

More info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Notification.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: thanks a lot! its simple but there is something i dont get, i want to notify classB on a change only if a SPECIFIC NSString was change in classA, how that goes with your code ?

Comment: I edited the answer and added an example. I didn't test it, but it should work. Let me know if it's not working.

Comment: Also, it's good practice to `#define` such constant strings: `#define NOTE_NAME @"noteName"` and use `NOTE_NAME` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want to implement the  [Observer Pattern](http://www.a-coding.com/2010/10/observer-pattern-in-objective-c.html)

Answer (score 2):

As ennuikiller suggested, an easy way to implement an observer pattern in obj-c is to use `NSNotificationCenter` class. For further info [see its class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**Edit**

An other way is using KVO (Key Value Observing). This is more complicated but has better performances respect to the first one. For a simple explanation see [Jeff Lamarche blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/kvo-and-iphone-sdk.html) and [KVO Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope it helps.