# General OOP paradigm for multiplayer hotseat turn based board game

Tags: cocoa, oop, object

So i'm working on a pretty basic turn based board game, and i'm trying to figure out the best way to structure it. I've already restructured the thing like 3 times. It's a cocoa project for mac.

The game starts with each player having $5000 and the ability to buy some of 6 different stocks. Each turn begins with the player rolling 3 dice which determines how the stocks' values change and how much money is made off of dividends if any. The game ends when the timer runs out, which is set before the game starts.

I'm right in the middle of programming it and i realized the way i'm going about it might not be advantages for... well, anything. :) Go noobs!

I'm trying to stick to the whole mvc paradigm, so my dice role generator is my model and the controller interacts with the interface. I have a really good grasp of mvc, i feel.

My app delegate calls the main xib which interacts with my "stockwindowcontroller" class which kinda controls everything else. The player window (which i haven't done yet) would show the player his assets and give him the possibility to buy and sell. I'd have to place it under the stockwindowcontroller class if i went with what i have right now.

I'm thinking maybe each turn it's own object, because sometimes there'll be like 50 turns. So everything comes out of the turn object. That would mean redoing everything again, and i'd like to make sure im not barking up the wrong tree... again. I've never been good at conceptualizing OOP thinking, forgive me if this is super obvious.

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing mvc, i usually start with a command line view and then add stuff until things settle down. Then add gui stuff. Always keep the command line view and controller as they are extremely useful for testing.

Try starting with something like this:

edit: refactored code so observer gets notified when a players money changes or he busts out.

```
import java.util.*;
class DiceRoller {
    DiceRoller(final int sides) {
        this(1,sides);
    }
    DiceRoller(final int dice,final int sides) {
        this.sides=sides;
        this.dice=dice;
    }
    int roll() {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<dice;i++)
            sum+=random.nextInt(sides)+1;
        return sum;
    }
    final Random random=new Random();
    final int dice;
    final int sides;
}
class Stock {
    Stock(int price) {
        this.price=price;
    }
    int value;
    int dividend;
    final int id=ids++;
    final int price;
    static int ids;
    public String toString() {
        return ""+id+" "+value+" "+dividend;
    }
}
class Player {
    public void turn() {
        System.out.print("turn for player "+id);
        int die1=diceRoller.roll();
        System.out.print(", he rolls "+die1);
        money+=die1-5; // real simple for now
        System.out.println(", he has "+money);
    }
    public String toString() {
        String s=""+id+" $"+money;
        if(stocks.size()>0)
            s+=" stocks";
        for(Stock stock:stocks.keySet())
            s+=" "+stock+" "+stocks.get(stock);
        return s;
    }
    Map<Stock,Integer> stocks=new LinkedHashMap<Stock,Integer>();
    int money=10;
    final int id=ids++;
    DiceRoller diceRoller=new DiceRoller(6);
    static int ids;
}
class Model extends Observable {
    void init(int stocks,int players) {
        for(int i=0;i<stocks;i++)
            this.stocks.add(new Stock(random.nextInt(10)+1));
        for(int i=0;i<players;i++)
            this.players.add(new Player());
        setChanged();
    }
    void turn(Player player) {
        player.turn();
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
    void busted(List<Player> busted) {
        if(busted.size()>0) {
            players.removeAll(busted);
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
        String s="";
        for(Stock stock:stocks)
            s+="stock "+stock+"\n";
        for(Player player:players)
            s+="player "+player+"\n";
        s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1); // removed last line feed
        return s;
    }
    Random random=new Random();
    final List<Stock> stocks=new ArrayList<Stock>();
    final List<Player> players=new ArrayList<Player>();
}
class CommandLineView implements Observer {
    @Override public void update(Observable observable,Object hint) {
        if(observable instanceof Model)
            display((Model)observable);
        else throw new RuntimeException("oops");
    }
    void display(Model model) {
        System.out.println("[update: "+model);
        System.out.println("end of update]");
    }
}
class Game {
    Game() {
        model=new Model();
        view=new CommandLineView();
        model.addObserver(view);
        model.init(4,3);
        model.notifyObservers();
    }
    void run() {
        for(round=0;model.players.size()>1;round++) {
            System.out.println("round "+round);
            for(Player player:model.players)
                model.turn(player);
            List<Player> busted=new ArrayList<Player>();
            for(Player player:model.players)
                if(player.money<=0) {
                    System.out.println("player "+player.id+" busted out.");
                    busted.add(player);
                }
            model.busted(busted);
            if(round>10) {
                System.out.println("breaking out");
                break;
            }
        }
        if(model.players.size()==1)
            System.out.println("the winner is "+model.players.get(0));
    }
    final Model model;
    Observer view;
    int player;
    int round;
}
public class So15578233 {
    void run() {
        game=new Game();
        game.run();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new So15578233().run();
    }
    Game game;
}
```

Comment: Well that's super impressive! You pretty much made the inner workings of my game in like no time at all. sadly i forgot to mention in my question i'm using objective c, trying to make a mac application. I don't have any experience with java's syntax, though it's a lot like c and i have messed with that before.

Comment: mvc mini architecture is based on the observer design pattern. ios examples are at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454074/register-a-class-in-objective-c, http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/12/patterns-in-objective-c-observer-pattern/, http://www.a-coding.com/2010/10/observer-pattern-in-objective-c.html, andhttp://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html